# how to show an image after pca?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I have a RGB image. I want to apply PCA for image-compression and see the output after the application.

Here's what I tried to do:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

------

def load_image(infilename):
   img = Image.open(infilename)
   img.load()   
   img.show()
   data = np.asarray(img, dtype="int32")
   return data
---------

data = load_image("Image_for_pca.jpg")
r = data[:,:,0]
print("r", r.shape)
g = data[:,:,1]
print("g", g.shape)
b = data[:,:,2]
print("b", b.shape)
concat_matrix_image = np.hstack((np.hstack((r,g)),b))
print("concatMatrixImage", concat_matrix_image.shape)

output of the prints:
r (161, 212)
g (161, 212)
b (161, 212)
concatMatrixImage (161, 636)

# list of dimension
pca_number_of_wanted_dimension = [3 ,5 ,10 ,15 ,20 ,30]
-------
def create_pca_model(number_of_components):
   pca = PCA(n_components=number_of_components)
   return pca
-------
def plot_varience_on_pca(pca):
   plt.plot(np.cumsum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_))
   plt.title("The number of wanted dimension is {}".format(pca.n_components))
   plt.xlabel('number of components')
   plt.ylabel('cumulative explained variance')
   plt.show()
   ------
   def recover_pic(pca, principal_components):
   #Project lower dimension data onto original features
   approximation = pca.inverse_transform(principal_components)    
   approximation = approximation.reshape(-1,161,212)

   # approximation = approximation.astype(np.uint8)
   # print(approximation.shape)
   # img = Image.fromarray(approximation, 'RGB')
   approximation.show()
   -------
   
   for i in pca_number_of_wanted_dimension:
      pca =  create_pca_model(i)
      principal_components = pca.fit_transform(concat_matrix_image)
      print(principal_components.shape)
      recover_pic(pca, principal_components)
      plot_varience_on_pca(pca)
```

How to recover the picture after the `pca.inverse_transform`?

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have your data, I have to show you how you can do using my data.

- Loading data and displaying data

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_olivetti_faces
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots
from matplotlib.pyplot import suptitle
from matplotlib.pyplot import savefig
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA


def display_set(n_row, n_col, x, y_, t, title="Id:{}",
                fig_size=(6, 3), dpi_=300, f_name="default.png"):
    fig, ax = subplots(n_row, n_col, figsize=fig_size, dpi=dpi_)
    ax = ax.flatten()

    for i in range(n_row * n_col):
        ax[i].imshow(X=x[i], cmap='gray')
        ax[i].set_xticks([])
        ax[i].set_yticks([])
        ax[i].set_title(title.format(y_[i]))
    suptitle(t=t)
    savefig(f_name)


olivetti = fetch_olivetti_faces()

X = olivetti.images  # Train
y = olivetti.target  # Labels

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
                                                    test_size=0.3,
                                                    random_state=42)

train_name = "train_samples.png"
test_name = "test_samples.png"
display_set(n_row=2, n_col=10, x=x_train, y_=y_train,
            t="Train-set samples", title="Id:{}", f_name=train_name)
display_set(n_row=2, n_col=10, x=x_test, y_=y_test,
            t="Test-set samples", title="Id:{}", f_name=test_name)
```

The output of train samples:

[image]

The output of test samples:

[image]

Now lets create a `pca` object

```
x_train = x_train.reshape((x_train.shape[0], X.shape[1] * X.shape[2]))
x_test = x_test.reshape((x_test.shape[0], X.shape[1] * X.shape[2]))
pca_train = PCA(n_components=100).fit(X=x_train)
pca_test = PCA(n_components=100).fit(X=x_test)
eig_num_tr = len(pca_train.components_)
eig_num_te = len(pca_test.components_)
# eigen training faces
eig_tr_faces = pca_train.components_.reshape((eig_num_tr, X.shape[1], X.shape[2]))  
# eigen test faces
eig_te_faces = pca_test.components_.reshape((eig_num_te, X.shape[1], X.shape[2]))  
title_tr = "PCA Applied Train-set samples"
title_te = "PCA Applied Test-set samples"
t_ = "Eig. Id:{}"

display_set(n_row=2, n_col=5, x=eig_tr_faces, y_=range(0, eig_num_tr-1), 
            t=title_tr, title=t_, fig_size=(6, 3.2))
display_set(n_row=2, n_col=5, x=eig_te_faces, y_=range(0, eig_num_te-1), 
            t=title_te, title=t_, fig_size=(6, 3.2))
```

The output of the training set:
[image]

The output of the test set:
[image]

Comment: this seems weird - you dont use the train PCA over the test PCA ..

Comment: But I want to show the principal components of each set separately. So, when will you use train pca over test pca? The answer is when you are labeling the faces. Your classifier learns from train images, then you apply on the test images to see the accuracy of your classifier. The higher accuracy mean, the most discriminative features are selected